# Plotting expression data based on a label and time

Tags: r, visualization

I have some data that I would like to visualize but I cannot manage to do this..

I have this play sheet:

```
 label <- c("t","x","t","x","t","t","t","x","t","x")
    t0 <- c(1:10) 
    t1 <- c(3:12) 
    t2 <- c(6:15)
    t3 <- c(8:17) 
    data <- data.frame(t0, t1, t2, t3, label)
```

The beginning looks like this

```
   t0 t1 t2 t3  label

1   1  3  6  8   t
2   2  4  7  9   x
3   3  5  8  10  t
4   4  6  9  11  x
```

I would like to plot the values of all samples (rows), as a line against the four time points(t=0,1,2,3). Furthermore I would like to color the lines with label t in one color and the label x in another. So in the play data I would end up with 10 lines of which 6 would be one color and 4 another.

I would appreciate all help! I tried some things using mathplot and ggplot but I am really stuck

Comment: Please provide a valid dataset. `t=0 <- c(1:10)` is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll bite.

As mentioned in the comments, your code will not currently work in R. I tried to structure my answer so that it will work with dataframes essentially identical to one you supplied, but I had to make a slight change to the code, which I show below:

```
label <- c("t","x","t","x","t","t","t","x","t","x")
t0 <- c(1:10) 
t1 <- c(3:12) 
t2 <- c(6:15)
t3 <- c(8:17) 
data <- data.frame(t0, t1, t2, t3, label)
```

If we're going to use `ggplot`, it we need to get your data into what's called long form using the `reshape2` package. This occurs during the `melt` step. Note that `variable` will become our `time` column. During the sequence of operations on ndata, we are constantly referring back to the `ndata` object. This is so that you can follow the code step-by-step.

We're also going to need some packages, which we'll load now:

```
# load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

data$sample_id <- as.character(rownames(data))

ndata <- melt(data, id = c("sample_id", "label")) # melt "data" into long form
ndata <- arrange(ndata, sample_id) # re-order rows by sample_id. Helpful for viewing dataframe
ndata <- mutate(ndata, variable = gsub("t", "", ndata$variable)) # remove the "t" character
ndata <- rename(ndata, time = variable)
ndata <- mutate(ndata, time = as.numeric(time)) # Make sure that time is numeric

newplot <- ggplot(ndata, aes(x = time, y = value, color = label, group = sample_id)) +
           geom_point() +
           geom_line()
newplot
```

[image: Generated Plot]